# NUMA-aware named shared memory for Linux

Tags: linux, memory, shared, numa

The Windows API offers the CreateFileMappingNuma function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366539(v=vs.85).aspx) to create a named shared memory space on a specific NUMA node.

So far, I have not found an equivalent function for Linux.

My current approach looks like this:

1. Allocate named shared memory (using shm_open(...))
2. Determine current NUMA node (using numa_move_pages(...))
3. Move pages to target Node (using numa_move_pages(...) again)

Does anyone know a better approach?

EDIT: For the record: My proposed implementation does work as expected!

Comment: Note that other apps mapping the same memory may move it to a different node later. On top of that, it is always better to have memory on "consumer" node as writes to a remote memory do not usually stall compared to reading from a remote memory.

Comment: I moved the memory to a specific node for that exact reason (to get the data close to a CPU). However, the scheduler is quite good at doing that himself, as I found out ;-). The only advantage this offers is, that all the memory pages are already in the right place, so you don't have the "priming" phase in the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds right.  Note that there are no pages allocated at the point where you call shm_open()/fruncate() (don't forget ftruncate() to set the size!).  The kernel simply creates the vma and waits for future code accesses to fault the pages into physical memory.  So calling numa_move_pages() in this state will presumably have the effect of creating and populating new pages in the relevant NUMA nodes.